# Thread safe OutputStreamWriter

Tags: java

Is there any thread-safe substitute for [`java.io.OutputStreamWriter`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/OutputStreamWriter.html) in the JDK or some third party library?

Comment: "Thread-safe" could mean lots of different things. Please explain what you mean exactly.

Comment: Thread safe means exactly one thing every time , that its methods can be accessed from multiple threads without breaking the invariant of the class.

Comment: @aix, please tell us the different things thread-safe could mean.

Comment: So you'd accept an implementation that would allow calling `write(char[],int,int)` on the same instance concurrently from two threads, and would randomly interleave bits of the two arrays on the underlying stream? I don't see any stated `OutputStreamWriter` invariants that this would violate.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

None that I know of.

But you can use other means to effectively achieve thread-safety, like protecting the OutputStreamWriter with some monitor, Lock, or Semaphore. Also, you can use a single-threaded ExecutorService as a unique bottleneck through which other threads submit writing "jobs".

Answer (score 1):

I answered this question: [Write to FileOutputStream from multiple threads in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8422278/write-to-fileoutputstream-from-multipes-threads-in-java/8422321#8422321)

, which is exactly the same.

The short answer is no, but there are ways around it.