# How do I get multiple threads to write data to a file

Tags: android

I have 5 uicontrols, custom ui that i have written by extending views.
All of them support gestures, i want to write the timestamp of each gesture from each ui to a file.
The file will be created at runtime on the sdcard.

I have created a singleton object - its instantiated in each ui view. I am passing in the timestamp each time there is a gesture on the view (views have gestures like zoom/pan etc).

So how do i write these timestamps to a file that i created in the singleton object.

Answer (score 0):

You can use your Singleton object and get the timestamps and put them in a queue; then you can de-queue timestamps and write them to your file!

Answer (score 0):

You can use [java.nio.channels.FileChannel](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/nio/channels/FileChannel.html) do synchronized writing to a file.

Take a look at this the following post for an example implementation.

[Write to FileOutputStream from multiple threads in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8422278/write-to-fileoutputstream-from-multiple-threads-in-java/10339404#10339404)